# FSM sequence detector in Verilog

Tags: verilog, state-machines, sequence-detector

I'm designing a finite state machine (FSM) to detect the sequence "10001" in Verilog.

I'm having a similar problem to that described in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157908/sequence-detector-in-verilog) in that my FSM does not tick when the sequence is seen but the solution to that problem does not apply in my case.

This is my FSM design:
[image]

Here is my verilog code for the FSM.

```
module fsm_detector(
input wire clk, reset,
input wire sequence,
output reg tick
);

// FSM state declarations
parameter A = 3'b000;
parameter B = 3'b001;
parameter C = 3'b010;
parameter D = 3'b011;
parameter E = 3'b100;

//signal declaration
reg [2:0] state_reg;
reg [2:0] state_next;

// state register logic
// asynchrous reset
always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if(reset)
        state_reg <= A;
    else
        state_reg <= state_next;

//next-state logic and output logic
always @ *
begin
    state_next = state_reg; // default state: the same
    tick = 1'b0; // default tick = 0
    case(state_reg)
        A:  if(sequence) // sequence = 1
                state_next = B;
            // else stay in A
        B:  if (~sequence)
                state_next = C;
            // else stay in B
        C:  
            if (~sequence)
                state_next = D;
            else
                state_next = B;
        D:  
            if(~sequence)
                state_next = E;
            else
                state_next = B;
        E:  if(sequence)
                begin
                    tick = 1'b1;
                    state_next = B;
                end
             else
                state_next = A;
       default: 
                state_next = A;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

And testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns
module fsm_detector_tb();
    //declerations
    parameter T = 20; //clock period in nanoseconds
    reg clk, reset;
    reg test_input;
    wire test_tick;


    fsm_detector uut(
        .clk(clk),
        .reset(reset),
        .sequence(test_input),
        .tick(test_tick)
        );

    // clock
    // 20 ns clock running forever
    always
    begin
        clk = 1'b1; //high
        #(T/2); // delay half a period
        clk = 1'b0; //low
        #(T/2); // delay half a period
    end

    initial
    begin
        reset = 1'b1;
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(2*T); // delay two clock cycle

        reset = 1'b0;
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle

        $finish;

    end


endmodule
```

The FSM should tick high at the point marked below:

[image: Simulation output]

Any suggestions?

Simulation output showing state transitions:
[image]

Comment: Look at the internal signals to see if the state is changing at all.

Comment: @Matt The internal 'state_reg'  signal changes as follows:  
state_reg = X 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 4 1 . 
sequence = 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1

Comment: So you did go from E back to B (4 to 1) which should trigger your output. I don't know. Did you confirm that tick didn't assert inside the dut (just to make sure your connections are sound)?

Comment: Wait you stayed in E for 2 consecutive cycles. That's impossible according to your verilog. Are you sure you're looking at the latest waves?

Comment: In the tb you use blocking assignments for both clk and signal. I don't remember offhand but I think I use nonblocking for signals and blocking for clk. You might have a classic verilog race condition.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was looking at the wrong thing for state_reg before. I've updated the original post with a picture of the simulation waveform showing state_reg now

Comment: Changing to non blocking statements for clk in testbench didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You got it backwards. The clock assignments should stay with blocking, but the assignments to test_input should be non-blocking. I just confirmed this is what I do in one of my old tbs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant blocking before. I use blocking (<=) for clk in testbench, still the same issue.

Comment: Blocking is =, nonblocking is <=. Clk gets plain =.

Comment: Changing the signal assignments to non blocking (<=) in testbench solved the issue. Thanks @Matt

Comment: Great, just created an official answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signal (non clock) assignments in a testbench should generally be non blocking (<= operator). Clock assignments should be blocking (= operator). Otherwise there's a race condition.

There are probably exceptions to this rule, but it works for me. Beyond that you need a good understanding of the verilog simulation phases. This rule of thumb will work for you 95% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the race condition in your code at state assignment , usually people will use #TCQ in NBA assignment and to look similar to hardware transiton.

```
module fsm_detector(
    input wire clk, reset,
    input wire sequence,
    output reg tick
);

    // FSM state declarations
    parameter A = 3'b000;
    parameter B = 3'b001;
    parameter C = 3'b010;
    parameter D = 3'b011;
    parameter E = 3'b100;

    //signal declaration
    reg [2:0] state;
    reg [2:0] next;

  // state register logic
  // asynchrous reset
  always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
      if(reset) state <= #10 A;
      else      state <= #10 next;

  //next-state logic and output logic
   always @ * begin
       next = state; // default state: the same
       tick = 1'b0;  // default tick = 0
       case(state)
           A:  if ( sequence)  next = B;
           B:  if (~sequence)  next = C;
           C:  if (~sequence)  next = D;
               else            next = B;
           D:  if (~sequence)  next = E;
               else            next = B;
           E:  if ( sequence) begin
                       tick = 1'b1;
                               next = B;
               end else        next = A;
          default:             next = A;
       endcase
    end

endmodule
```

Simulation output with modified code and adding #TCQ to NBA(Non-Blocking Assignments) assignments 
[image]